# PySpark lead function timestamp default value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I have the following code:

```py
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, lead, first, last

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("120", "aaaaa", "2021-11-19 08:00", 3.2),  
        ("120", "aaaaa", "2021-11-19 10:00", 3.3),
        ("120", "aaaaa", "2021-11-20 08:00", 3.1),
        ("120", "aaaaa", "2021-11-20 15:00", 2.4),
        ("150", "bbbbb", "2021-11-19 08:45", 2.7),
        ("150", "bbbbb", "2021-11-19 09:00", 2.2),
        ("150", "bbbbb", "2021-11-19 14:00", 2.1),
        ("150", "bbbbb", "2021-11-19 21:00", 2.9),
        ("150", "bbbbb", "2021-11-19 23:00", 2.4),
        ("203", "ccccc", "2021-11-19 08:00", 2.1),
        ("203", "ccccc", "2021-11-19 09:00", 2.3),
        ("203", "ccccc", "2021-11-19 10:00", 2.4),
        ("203", "ccccc", "2021-11-19 11:00", 2.2)
    ],
    ["id_1", "id_2", "ts", "value"]  
)

#convert string to timestamp
df_ts = df.withColumn("startts",to_timestamp('ts', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')).drop('ts')

#add endts as startts from next row
df_h = df_ts.withColumn('endts', lead('startts', 1).over(Window.partitionBy('id_1', 'id_2').orderBy('startts')))
```

So at the end I get a dataframe with startts and endts:

| id_1 | id_2 | value | startts | endts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | aaaaa | 3.2 | 2021-11-19 08:00:00 | 2021-11-19 10:00:00 |
| 120 | aaaaa | 3.3 | 2021-11-19 10:00:00 | 2021-11-20 08:00:00 |
| 120 | aaaaa | 3.1 | 2021-11-20 08:00:00 | 2021-11-20 15:00:00 |
| 120 | aaaaa | 2.4 | 2021-11-20 15:00:00 | null |
| 150 | bbbbb | 2.7 | 2021-11-19 08:45:00 | 2021-11-19 09:00:00 |
| 150 | bbbbb | 2.2 | 2021-11-19 09:00:00 | 2021-11-19 14:00:00 |
| 150 | bbbbb | 2.1 | 2021-11-19 14:00:00 | 2021-11-19 21:00:00 |
| 150 | bbbbb | 2.9 | 2021-11-19 21:00:00 | 2021-11-19 23:00:00 |
| 150 | bbbbb | 2.4 | 2021-11-19 23:00:00 | null |
| 203 | ccccc | 2.1 | 2021-11-19 08:00:00 | 2021-11-19 09:00:00 |
| 203 | ccccc | 2.3 | 2021-11-19 09:00:00 | 2021-11-19 10:00:00 |
| 203 | ccccc | 2.4 | 2021-11-19 10:00:00 | 2021-11-19 11:00:00 |
| 203 | ccccc | 2.2 | 2021-11-19 11:00:00 | null |

Now I would like to have to have "9999-12-31 23:59" in endts column instead of "null". I have tried doing so by setting a default value for the function lead using lit and to_timestamp, but it has not worked.

Is it possible to set a timestamp literal for the default value of lead?

Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that just using the string "9999-12-31 23:59" as default value works! O_o

Comment: Yea, just set `default="9999-12-31 23:59"` for `lead`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that just using the string "9999-12-31 23:59" as default value works! My last line thus become:

```py
df_h = df_ts.withColumn(
  'endts', 
  lead('startts', 1, '9999-12-31 23:59').over(Window.partitionBy('id_1', 'id_2').orderBy('startts'))
)
```